# How do I trick multiple inheritance in Android

Tags: java, android, multiple-inheritance

I have faced a problem when `Activity` needs to extend both `ActionBarActivity` and `ListActivity` simultaneously.

Are there any ways to trick this? I know that java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

---

*The problem as follows*:

I've created auto-generated `NavigationDrawer` application and the `MainActivity` should extend `ActionBarActivity` to get this navigation panel work properly.

And on the other hand I need a `ListView` ([this library](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)) to be used in `MainActivity` as a content. And the problem is that `ListView` library requires **`ListActivity`** to be extended.

So I have 2 required extends..

---

Are there any non-painful ways to solve such situations?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the answer is no.

Comment: just implement the list yourself !

Comment: Why not just add a ```ListView``` to the layout of your ```ActionBarActivity```?

Comment: There is also the google [`SwipeRefreshLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) that may be of use

Comment: Since the documentation for the library says nothing about `ListActivity`, and since the source code to the library does not reference `ListActivity`, I am not quite certain how you have determined that the library requires `ListActivity`.

Comment: Can you put your content in a fragment?